# Create class which represents collection of Employees

Tags: javascript, json, class, abstract-class, ecmascript-5

I have abstract Class `AbstractEmployee` and two concrete sub-classes `FixedSalaryEmployee` and `PerHourSalaryEmployee` which inherit from `AbstractEmployee` and override its abstract `getSalary` method with correct implementation for given employye type.

First implementation `FixedSalaryEmployee` - Employee with fixed salary. Where average monthly salary is equal to employee the value of salary in JSON data.

Second implementation `PerHourSalaryEmployee`- Employee with per-hour salary. Where hour rate is equal to the value of salary in JSON data, working day has 8 hours and month has 20.88 working days in average.

And create Collection class which is able to work with employees of different types.

The main question is how to сreate `EmployeeCollection` class which represents collection of Employees:

- Constructor should accept data from JSON file and create instances of corresponding classes based on `type` field.

  - id should be generated in a format `id<number>` e.g. (`id0`, `id1` etc. for each item in collection)
- Items in collection should be sorted by the next rules:

  - Sort all employees in descending order of average monthly salary.
  - If average monthly salary of employees is equal use employee name instead.

Need use ES5!

```js
//AbstractEmployee.js
var AbstractEmployee = function(id, name, salary) {
    if (this.constructor === AbstractEmployee) {
      throw new Error("Can't instantiate abstract class!");
    }

    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary; 

    if(typeof(object.id) !== 'string' || typeof(object.name) !== 'string' || typeof(object.salary) !== 'number'){
        throw new Error("Wrong param passed!");
    }
};

AbstractEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
    throw new Error('Method getSalary() must be implemented');
}

//PerHourSalaryEmployee.js
var AbstractEmployee = require('./AbstractEmployee.js')

var PerHourSalaryEmployee = function(id, name, salary) { 
    AbstractEmployee.apply(this, arguments)
    this.id = 'id' + id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary * 20.88 * 8; 
 };
 PerHourSalaryEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
    return this.salary;
}

module.exports = PerHourSalaryEmployee

//FixedSalaryEmployee.js
var AbstractEmployee = require('./AbstractEmployee.js')

var FixedSalaryEmployee = function(id, name, salary) {
    AbstractEmployee.apply(this, arguments);
    this.id = 'id' + id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary; 
};

FixedSalaryEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
    return this.salary;
}

module.exports = FixedSalaryEmployee
```

**employees-collection.json**

```
[{
  "type": "per-hour",
  "salary": 10,
  "name": "Anna"
},
{
  "type": "per-hour",
  "salary": 8,
  "name": "Bob"
},
{
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 8000,
  "name": "Dany"
},
{
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 8000,
  "name": "Clara"
},
{
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 1000,
  "name": "Egor"
}]
```

Comment: The collection class should have an instance variable containing an array of `AbstractEmployee`. When it processes the JSON, it calls either `PerHourSalaryEmployee()` or `FixedSalaryEmployee()`, and pushes the employee onto the array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: 1/2 ... 1st) `AbstractEmployee` is not used as a class (constructor). It is merely used as function based mixin. Thus the implementation of `AbstractEmployee.prototype.getSalary` is just a waste of characters. ... 2nd) Both constructor functions, `PerHourSalaryEmployee` and `FixedSalaryEmployee` do each independently create instances with a set of equally named properties (`id`, `name`, `salary `) which renders the `apply`ing of the `AbstractEmployee` in both constructor functions almost entirely useless.

Comment: 2/2 ... _**conclusion** ... `AbstractEmployee` is almost entirely dead code. How it gets used by the example does not effect anything differently from what already gets achieved by each of the other constructor functions alone, except for the type checking of the arguments which itself is wrongly implemented (there is no `object` scope)._ **possible solution** ... rename `AbstractEmployee` to e.g. `typeCheckEmployeeArguments` strip all the unnecessary code and implement the type checking correctly which makes it clearly a simple helper function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was already commented, a half baked `AbstractEmployee` function used merely as a function based mixin does not make real sense.

A pure old school (it was asked for / limited to ES5-syntax) inheritance approach is much better suitable.

And one actually does not even need a `BaseEmployee` constructor since the features of a `FixedSalaryEmployee` type are totally equal to the ones of a `BaseEmployee` type, and the `PerHourSalaryEmployee` type differs only in the internal/initial computation of its `salary` property(, but one never knows what the future still might bring) ...

```js
function orderBySalaryDescendingAndNameAscending(a, b) {
  return (b.salary - a.salary) || a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
}

// employee factory.
function createTypeDependedEmployeeVariant(rawData, idx) {
  const { type, name, salary } = rawData;

  const employee = (type === 'per-hour')
    ? new PerHourSalaryEmployee(String(idx), name, salary)
    : new FixedSalaryEmployee(String(idx), name, salary)

  // employee.type = type;
  return employee;
}

// employee list factory.
function createOrderedListOfVariousEmployeeInstances(arr) {
  return arr
    .map(createTypeDependedEmployeeVariant)
    .sort(orderBySalaryDescendingAndNameAscending);
}

const jsonDataList = [{
  "type": "per-hour",
  "salary": 10,
  "name": "Anna"
}, {
  "type": "per-hour",
  "salary": 8,
  "name": "Bob"
}, {
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 8000,
  "name": "Dany"
}, {
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 8000,
  "name": "Clara"
}, {
  "type": "fixed",
  "salary": 1000,
  "name": "Egor"
}];

console.log(
  createOrderedListOfVariousEmployeeInstances(jsonDataList)
    .map(({ id, name, salary }) => ({ id, name, salary }))
);
console.log(
  createOrderedListOfVariousEmployeeInstances(jsonDataList)
    .map(item => item.getSalary())
);
console.log(
  createOrderedListOfVariousEmployeeInstances(jsonDataList)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script>
  function BaseEmployee(id, name, salary) {
    if (
      (typeof id !== 'string') ||
      (typeof name !== 'string') ||
      (typeof salary !== 'number') ||
      !Number.isFinite(salary)
    ) {
      throw new TypeError('Wrong parameter(s) passed!');
    }
    this.id = 'id' + id;
    this.name = name;
    this.salary = salary;
  }
  BaseEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
    return this.salary;
  }
</script>

<script>
  function PerHourSalaryEmployee (id, name, salary) {
    // super call.
    BaseEmployee.apply(this, arguments);

    this.salary = (salary * 20.88 * 8);
  };
  // extend superclass.
  PerHourSalaryEmployee.prototype = Object.create(BaseEmployee.prototype);

  // prevent super constructor from being the sub-classed constructor.
  PerHourSalaryEmployee.prototype.constructor = PerHourSalaryEmployee;
</script>

<script>
  function FixedSalaryEmployee(id, name, salary) {
    // super call.
    BaseEmployee.apply(this, arguments);
  };
  // extend superclass.
  FixedSalaryEmployee.prototype = Object.create(BaseEmployee.prototype);

  // prevent super constructor from being the sub-classed constructor.
  FixedSalaryEmployee.prototype.constructor = FixedSalaryEmployee;
</script>
```

The most optimized `Employee`-class code-base would/could look like the below provided code. There is no difference in its usage with the above provided factories in comparison to the above code base which features the additional `BaseEmployee` ...

```
function checkEmployeeArguments(id, name, salary) {
  if (
    (typeof id !== 'string') ||
    (typeof name !== 'string') ||
    (typeof salary !== 'number') ||
    !Number.isFinite(salary)
  ) {
    throw new TypeError('Wrong parameter(s) passed!');
  }
}

function FixedSalaryEmployee(id, name, salary) {
  checkEmployeeArguments(id, name, salary);

  this.id = 'id' + id;
  this.name = name;
  this.salary = salary;
}
FixedSalaryEmployee.prototype.getSalary = function() {
  return this.salary;
}
```

```
function PerHourSalaryEmployee (id, name, salary) {
  // super call.
  FixedSalaryEmployee.apply(this, arguments);

  this.salary = (salary * 20.88 * 8);
};
// extend superclass.
PerHourSalaryEmployee.prototype = Object.create(FixedSalaryEmployee.prototype);

// prevent super constructor from being the sub-classed prototype constructor.
PerHourSalaryEmployee.prototype.constructor = PerHourSalaryEmployee;
```